# django auth class views vs function views

Tags: django

I am creating a website using django version 1.11.5, I was wondering is it better to use the auth class best views (LoginView, PasswordChangeView) or writing my own function based views. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always **better** to use the **class based Auth views** provided by django.

But if you are considering customization you can write your own views.